# Not able to find settings.xml file in maven repository

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have downloaded Eclipse mars3.1,in that in my .m2 folder i am not able to find settings.xml file.I searched about this topic in net ,then i found that there will be two places where settings.xml is found,i.e local and globaly(where we make locally by coping from global)but in my case i am not able to find both,what should i do now,i am trying this to deploy generated maven war file to tomcat

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: settings.xml file is not located in your local maven cache (.m2) but in your local maven installation folder (MAVEN_HOME/conf), check where you did install maven and in its conf subfolder you will find the settings.xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download [maven Binary zip archive (apache-maven-3.3.1-bin.zip)](http://www.us.apache.org/dist//maven/maven-3/3.3.1/binaries/), then unzip the folder, you will find the `setting.xml` file inside the config folder.

If you have already set the path of maven (environment variables), then simply copy and keep the `setting.xml` inside config folder of your maven installation directory.